# chained position animations with jquery animate()

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate

i would like to have a set of 11 elements "fly" into a page - by a chained set of animations using jQuery animate().

i have the following: http://bit.ly/g90S3J 
which seems to work quite well in FF3.6
but i see that in IE8 -the animations and positions are way off - with elements remaining off the stage, or flying of the stage, whereas in FF, they collect around the center, as they should.

what sometimes also seems to happen in FF, is that the final position of the elements seems to change on a sporadic basis once in a while. weird!!

can someone give me a hand here?

Many Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, item1 has a top margin of -1550px and when you animate it you are adding 1200px to it. It will still have a negative margin that is greater than its height.  Therefore, it will still be "hidden".

Comment: Nevermind, I see the `top` and `margin-top`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
.flyItem {
    display: inline;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When I mean to set an initial position just add:

```
  top:0;
   left:0;
```

To the properties and since you have:

```
$(function(){ 
       $("#item1").animate({'top': '+=1200px'},2000, 'swing', function(){
      $("#item2").animate({'right': '-=2630px'},3000, 'swing', function(){
        $("#item3").animate({'top': '-=2700px'},3000, 'swing');        
                                                                                         });                                                           
                                                                        }); 

       $("#item6").animate({'right': '+=1860px'},2000, 'swing', function(){
       $("#item5").animate({'top': '+=1000px'},3000, 'swing', function(){
        $("#item4").animate({'right': '+=1000px'},3000, 'swing');          
                                                                                });                                                        
                                                                        }); 


});
```

the 'flyItem'  elements must all  be inside a relatively positioned div.

Comment: You have to set an initial position for each element since IE8 is jerk.

Comment: @jesper: This is not an answer; it should have been a comment.

Comment: i tried adding the top:0;    left:0;
but there is still a difference between FF and IE.
take a look at the same link - i have just edited the position of the Blue star and Scroll - they look different in IE and FF.

Comment: ok - found the solution - the above works, when the moving elements are inside a relatively positioned div. (i edited the answer respectively)
thanks!